# Return different value depending on number of arguments in a function

Tags: python, python-3.x

Im trying to make a function that takes from 1 up to 5 arguments and does different calculations depending on the number given.
My idea was something like this:

```
def function(*args)
    num_of_args = (!!here is the problem!!)
if(num_of_args == 1) : result = a
else if(number_of_args == 2) : result = a+b
```

and so on
I have tried to count number of arguments and assign that number to a variable but can't find a way
I imagine that there is possibly no need to use 5 if's but I don't realy want to focus on it before I manage to count those arguments

Comment: You can get the number of arguments passed using `len(args)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `len(args)`.

```
def function(*args):
    if len(args) == 0:
        print("Number of args = 0")
    elif len(args) == 1:
        print("Number of args = 1")
    else:
        print("Number of args >= 2")
```

Comment: thank you! I'll accept this

Answer (score 3):

with `*args`, positional argumets are sent as list. You can access them using args[0],args[1].... also the length by len(args)

```
def foo(*args):
  print(len(args))
```

Comment: thanks, didn't know that!